# Ruby code to Separate Key value pairs in Logstash 6.8.0

Tags: ruby, logstash, key-value

```
ruby {
          code => "
          event['data'].each {|k, v|
          event[k] = v
          }
          event.remove('data')
        "
      }
```

> This was used earlier in logstash 1.5 to split key value pair from a field called "data". Currently we need to migrate to logstash 6.8.0, Could someone help me for this?

> I had Tried This, but It's not working properly

```
ruby {
code => "
event.get('data').each {|k, v|
event.set(k, v)
}
event.remove('data')
"
}
```

> > Log is like
> > {"data":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}]}

Comment: If [data] is an array of hashes then you should use event.get('[data][0]')

Comment: @Badger {"data":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}]} Like this the log has key: value more than 20 . And the key value count can change. I am receiving "Ruby Exception occurred: no implicit conversion of Array into String"

Comment: So [data] is an array containing a hash. `event.get('[data][0]').each {|k, v|` should work.

Comment: @Badger I am getting "This now  Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

ruby {
code => "
event.get('[data][0]').each {|k, v|
event.set(k, v)
}
event.remove('data')
"
}